# Salesforce Internal Errors with gack ids -1587737213, 830863575, -772922182, -1550386336, -1363044143, 984794114

Tags: salesforcedx, gack

I use CI script to run unit tests on every push to Github repository, I have a scratch org definition to create a scratch org, deploy the code from push and execute all unit tests.

This is the scratch org definition I use.

```
{
    "orgName": "Package Development",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": [],
    "settings": {
        "quoteSettings": {
            "enableQuote": true
        },
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true
        },
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableNameSuffix": false
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        }
    }
}
```

When the unit tests are executed, sometimes they fail with different Internal Salesforce Errors, in 1 of 10 cases. However, when the failed tests are rerun, they run successfully. This is the command I use to execute the unit tests

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --loglevel=trace -y -c -r json -d ./tests/apex -w 20
```

This is the list of Internal Salesforce errors I get

```
Internal Salesforce Error: 1950076781-132753 (-1587737213) (-1587737213)
Internal Salesforce Error: 1000731961-228013 (830863575) (830863575)
Internal Salesforce Error: 2063891872-100557 (-772922182) (-772922182)
Internal Salesforce Error: 1429891351-234111 (-1550386336) (-1550386336) 
Internal Salesforce Error: 1805172275-3633717 (-1363044143) (-1363044143)
Internal Salesforce Error: 444165804-2332782 (984794114) (984794114)
```

How do I overcome these errors?

Answer (score 3):

On the 6/14/2021 4:40 PM, I have opened a case with Salesforce Support to investigate this error.

On the 9/20/2021 11:14 AM, I received a suggestion with workaround of this issue.
Salesforce support suggested to turn on `"enableGaplessTestAutoNum": true` and `"enableDisableParallelApexTesting": true` and explained that when all tests are run, they run in parallel mode even though I use -y switch to use synchronous execution.

I see that the default value of `enableGaplessTestAutoNum` is true, so the only thing that matters here is the `enableDisableParallelApexTesting`. Anyway, when updated my scratch org definition file to this one

```
{
    "orgName": "Package Development",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": [],
    "settings": {
        "apexSettings": {
            "enableGaplessTestAutoNum": true, "enableDisableParallelApexTesting": true
        },
        "quoteSettings": {
            "enableQuote": true
        },
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true
        },
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableNameSuffix": false
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        }
    }
}
```

this error seems to be gone at least for several days.

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

Comment: you are welcome!